# Building a project using Boost with ArchLinux

Tags: boost, linker, autotools, archlinux

I have installed

```
extra/boost 1.52.0-1
extra/boost-libs 1.52.0-1
```

with pacman under ArchLinux. I'm trying to build autotools C++ projects which make use of parts of the Boost library. They have been successfully tested and build under Ubuntu 12.04. with installed `libboost-all-dev` package. With ArchLinux `./configure` works out fine and the  compilation process (`make`) seems to work, too. Nevertheless, there seems to be a problem with the linking:

```
 libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -o ssbmc smtparser.o ... 
 ../contrib/cudd 2.4.2/obj/.libs/libobj.a ... 
 -lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_iostreams-mt -lgmp -lgmpxx -lm -lz
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options-mt
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_iostreams-mt
```

Any ideas why it fails? The headers seems to be there since the source makes use of Boost library functions and compiling the files does not fail.

The libraries are there:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/ | grep program
libboost_program_options.a
libboost_program_options.so
libboost_program_options.so.1.52.0
$ ls /usr/lib/ | grep iostreams
libboost_iostreams.a
libboost_iostreams.so
libboost_iostreams.so.1.52.0
```

Do they have to be renamed?

Comment: Try search in configure script where wants *-mt files! Maybe is it hardcoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
$sudo ln -s libboost_program_options.so libboost_program_options-mt.so
$sudo ln -s libboost_iostreams.so libboost_iostreams-mt.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Boost libraries used to be called with suffices showing architecture which they were build for. For instance, -mt means 'multithreaded' or 'build in thread-aware mode'. As far as I know, this convention is not followed on Linux nowadays and libraries do not have that suffix by default (although they are still build in thread-aware mode). Your ./configure script generates instructions for linker in the old format. Try to use bjam, if you can. If you say

```
bjam --layout=tagged
```

you can even get your suffices back... Technically, your solution is perfectly valid as well :)

Comment: Thanks but that is a very big step switching the whole build system and I am not the only developer. Is there a stable autotools solution?